# Drop down menu only if checkbox ticked shiny app R

Tags: r, checkbox, drop-down-menu, shiny

I have a checkbox in shiny, and a `selectInput` drop down menu.

If the checkbox is ticked, then a plot will display showing the relevant data selected from the drop down menu.

If the checkbox is un-ticked, then the drop down menu is still visible, but the plot does not show.

How would I change it so that the drop down menu doesn't actually appear until the box is ticked?

An example of my code so far is something like this:

```
ui <- fluidPage(checkboxInput(inputId = "compare",label="Load new plot?",value=F),
                dateInput(inputId = "lowerlimit", label="Lower Date",value="2016-01-01"),
                dateInput(inputId = "upperlimit",label="Upper Date"),
                selectInput(inputId = "data2",label="Choose data source", choices="FILEPATHS"),
                plotOutput("plot",dblclick = "plot_dblclick", brush = brushOpts(id="plot_brush",resetOnNew = T)))

server <- function(input,output,session){

  autoInvalidate <- reactiveTimer(300000, session) #new

  ranges <- reactiveValues(x = NULL, y = NULL)

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    autoInvalidate() # Load new data every 5 minutes if available.
    if(input$compare==T){
      data2=read.csv(paste0("FILEPATH",input$data2,".csv"))

      if (!is.null(ranges$x)) {
        ggplot(data2, aes(Date, Data, group=1))+geom_line()+
          scale_x_datetime(limits=c(ranges$x), labels = date_format("%d-%m-%y %H:%M"))
      } else {
        ggplot(data2, aes(Date, Data, group=1))+geom_line()+
          scale_x_datetime(limits=c(as.POSIXct(input$lowerlimit), as.POSIXct(input$upperlimit)), labels = date_format("%d-%m-%y %H:%M"))
      }
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$plot_dblclick, {
    brush <- input$plot_brush
    if (!is.null(brush)) {
      ranges$x <- c(brush$xmin, brush$xmax)
      ranges$y <- c(brush$ymin, brush$ymax)

    } else {
      ranges$x <- NULL
      ranges$y <- NULL
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: You either use `conditionalPanels` or dynamically create the dropdown using `uiOutput`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should Work

```
conditionalPanel("input.compare",
selectInput(inputId = "data2",label="Choose data source", choices="FILEPATHS"))
```